# Why do CursorPositionChanged events stop flowing when I turn off IsUserSelectionEnabled?

Tags: winforms, events, charts

I want the user to be able to click on a Chart to relocate the X axis cursor. When the user does this, calculations need to occur and other controls need to update with new information. So I wrote a CursorPositionChanged handler in my main Form. It worked.

But I don't want the user to select a range, or have the chart zoom in along the X axis in case the user accidentally drags the mouse while attempting to just click.  So in the GUI designer I set the chart's IsUserSelectionEnabled to false, leaving IsUserEnabled true.

Now I get no CursorPositionChanged events!  Why?

As far as I understand, I'm doing this right, but am no expert on WinForms.  Is there some other setting I need to deal with?

Comment: Welcome to the joy of working with the Chart control.  I can verify your issue and can only offer a work-around.  Use the `Chart.CursorPositionChanging` instead of the `Chart.CursorPositionChanged`.

Comment: Ah good, Chart.CursorPositionChanging works fine in my app.  Make your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can verify your issue and can only offer a work-around.

Use the [Chart.CursorPositionChanging Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.cursorpositionchanging?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of the [Chart.CursorPositionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.cursorpositionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the CursorPositionChanging  event fires.  They both supply a [CursorEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.cursorpositionchanging?view=netframework-4.7.2) parameter.

I don't know why I bothered linking to the worthless documentation, but maybe someday it won't be worthless.